# Not able to enable ktls while build OpenSSL3.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, kernel, compiling, openssl, tls

I am trying to build Openssl-3.0.0 from master branch to use ktls feature on Ubuntu 16,  but the build is skipping the ktls feature

even though i am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 (Kernel version: 4.15) somehow this build is picking up older version of kernel headers which are not present in my host and skipping KTLS feature,

am i missing something here? can some please help me building this component?

Here are the steps

## Step 1: Verified Headers

```
kafka-secure2:/usr/src$ uname -a
Linux kafka-secure2 4.15.0-50-generic #54~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 8 15:55:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

kafka-secure2:/usr/src$ find . -name version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-52/include/xen/interface/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-52/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-50/include/linux/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-50/include/xen/interface/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-50/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h
./linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

## Step2 : Initiated Openssl Build

```
kafka-secure2:~/sanat/openssl-build$ $HOME/sanat/openssl-master/config enable-ktls --prefix=/home/kafka/openssl/openssl --openssldir=/home/kafka/openssl/ssl
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.0.0-dev for target linux-x86_64
Using os-specific seed configuration
cat: /usr/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory   <====================Still looking for this version.h


Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
kafka-secure2:~/sanat/openssl-build$ ./configdata.pm -o

Enabled features:

......

Disabled features:

    ktls                    [too-old-kernel] 
    asan                    [default]        OPENSSL_NO_ASAN
    buildtest-c++           [default]
```

## Step3: So i manually copied version.h from uapi to linux folder, this has latest version

```
linux-headers-4.15.0-50/         linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic/ linux-headers-4.15.0-52/         linux-headers-4.15.0-52-generic/ 
kafka-secure2:~/kafka/kafka_2.12-1.1.1$ cat /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 266002
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))


kafka-secure2:/usr/src$ cp  ./linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/include/linux/
```

## Step4: This time ktls was enabled in config

```
kafka-secure2:~/sanat/openssl-build$ $HOME/sanat/openssl-master/config enable-ktls --prefix=/home/kafka/openssl/openssl --openssldir=/home/kafka/openssl/ssl
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Configuring OpenSSL version 3.0.0-dev for target linux-x86_64
Using os-specific seed configuration
Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************

kafka-secure2:~/sanat/openssl-build$ ./configdata.pm -o

Enabled features:

    ktls
    afalgeng
    ...
```

## Step5: But the build skipped the KTLS feature

```
kafka-secure2:~/sanat/openssl-build$ make

ssl-master/providers/common/ciphers -I../openssl-master/crypto  -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DPOLY1305_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DX25519_ASM -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/home/kafka/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/home/kafka/openssl/openssl/lib/engines-3\"" -DMODULESDIR="\"/home/kafka/openssl/openssl/lib/ossl-modules\"" -DNDEBUG   -c -o crypto/bio/libcrypto-lib-bss_sock.o ../openssl-master/crypto/bio/bss_sock.c
In file included from ../openssl-master/crypto/bio/bss_sock.c:14:0:
../openssl-master/include/internal/ktls.h:23:7: warning: #warning "KTLS requires Kernel Headers >= 4.13.0" [-Wcpp]
 #     warning "KTLS requires Kernel Headers >= 4.13.0"
       ^
../openssl-master/include/internal/ktls.h:24:7: warning: #warning "Skipping Compilation of KTLS" [-Wcpp]
 #     warning "Skipping Compilation of KTLS"
       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the above issue with the Linux kernel 4.20.
I performed below steps:

1. Downloaded Linux kernel 4.20 and Enabled kernel TLS (CONFIG_TLS=y and CONFIG_TLS_DEVICE=y)
2. Compiled and installed the linux kernel 4.20
3. Cloned latest Openssl master code base ( till 14th September 2019) and executed below steps

   - ./config '-WL,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,$(LIBRPATH)' enable-ktls
   - make
   - make test
   - sudo make install

**I didn’t see any warning messages as mentioned above or compilation or Make test fail issues.**

I have gone through KTLS related commits available in both OpenSSL Master branch and Linux Kernel (till 14th September 2019).

Identified that  KTLS related breaks are there after Linux kernel version 4.20.

I am able to Compile and Make test is passed with Linux kernel version 4.20.

**Note:**

1. KTLS feature has merged into mainline Linux kernel after 4.13 and added TLS_RX after 4.17.
2. Make test(with OpenSSL master branch code) is failed in Linux kernel versions 5.0 and 5.2.11 due to the Linux kernel side KTLS breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your installed linux kernel headers version. The headers version should be greater than 4.17. The version is taken from:
`/usr/include/linux/version.h`

On my machine it is:

```
#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 329216
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))
```

Which stands for Linux 5.6.0

You can either install new kernel headers from source as described here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt

Or you can install the headers from your distribution as described here:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian/